# How to get a userName on the second service?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have two wcf services that are on different servers.
I call the first service:

```
var ms = new MessagesService.CommonClient();
ms.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
ms.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "12345";
string r = ms.GetStatus();
```

In this service there is a call of the second service:

```
public class MessagesService : ICommon
    {
        public string GetStatus()
        {
            var serviceSecond = new ProcessingService.ProcessingClient();
            try
            {
                status = serviceSecond.GetName();
                serviceSecond.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                serviceSecond.Abort();
                throw new FaultException(error.Message);
            }

            return status;
        }
}
```

In the first service I can get a username:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name //admin
```

Implementation of the second service:

```
public class ProcessingService : IProcessing
{   
    public string GetName()
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name; //WCF01 
    }
}
```

> The second service returns to me the name of the server on which the
>   first service (WCF01). How to get 'admin' on the second service?
>   Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is the second service on the same machine?  Is it on an intranet (authenticated via ActiveDirectory or Kerberos)?

Comment: These are different machines in the domain. (authenticated via ActiveDirectory)

Comment: how are the 2 services hosted. are they using windows auth?

Comment: Are you familiar with "the IIS double-hop" problem and configuring Kerberos trusts between servers (in Active Directory)?

Comment: This is not related to IIS. I do not need authentication. I need to get the first name for logging.